# Django Rest Framework - Check/manipulate data (by some logic) before saving to database

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. I have a serializer like this:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = (
            'user',
            'course',
            'major',
            'title',
            'text',
            'placements',
            'faculty',
            'infrastructure',
            'students',
            'extra_curricular',
            'passing_year',
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='reviews')
    course = models.ForeignKey(to=Course, related_name='reviews')
    major = models.ForeignKey(to=Major, related_name='reviews', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    text = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    placements = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    faculty = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    infrastructure = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    students = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    extra_curricular = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    passing_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=2014)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And the **views.py**

```
class ReviewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    College API
    """
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    paginate_by = 5
```

Now,whenever I post something to the API it directly gets saved to the database if the validation passes successfully. What I need is, I want to check and apply some conditions on the data using some business logic before it saves the data to the database. So that if the condition is true only then the data gets saved, or else it returns a error message to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite default create method inside ModelViewSet. This method is called when you post (POST http method) something to your API.
Then you can check if serialized data are valid and then apply your business logic befaore saving them:

```
class ReviewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    College API
    """
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    paginate_by = 5

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():

            #YOUR CODE HERE

            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using the new version 3.0. Then you need to put your validation logic into your serializer `ReviewSerializer` (See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers).

So if you want to create a validation of the fields you should overload the `def validate_<fieldname>(self, value)`. For example if you want `Review.placements` be `>= 0.0`, you may write

```py
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
[...]
    def validate_placements(self, value):
         if value >= 0.0:
              return value
         raise serializers.ValidationError('placements should be non-negative.')
[...]
```

If you need more advanced validation, e.g. to validate two dependent fields, then you need to  override the `def validate(self, attrs)`.

For example to have `created_on <= updated_on`

```py
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
[...]
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['created_on'] <= attrs['update_on']:
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Date of creation should be before update date.')
[...]
```

If you now add some objects over REST-API, the validation will be called automatically. You don't have to override the methods of `ModelViewSet`.

In the [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers) above and in [www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) are more hints.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning my DRF version in the first place. It is 2.4.3 (I commented to my question too). BTW, the first answer solved my problem. Thanks, anyways.